# AWS Boto3(Python): saving multiple response using Path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rekognition

from below script that I am using from AWS Rekognition (boto3 = python):

```
pics = [f'LP {num}.jpg' for num in range(1, 5)]
for pic in pics :
    request = {
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': 'test1',
            'Name': pic
        }
    }
 
response = client.detect_labels(Image=request)

json_file = json.dumps(response)
Path(f"{pic}.json").write_text(json_file)
```

I am trying to run 4 images named LP 1, LP 2, LP 3, and LP 4 and then save each response to an individual JSON file.

Question 1: I am not sure why but my script only saves one response file instead of all 4 images. For example, if I set the range to (1,5), only the response for LP 4 is saved. If I set the range to (1,4), only the response for LP 3 is saved.

Question 2: I am trying to save the response in a specific format using below script but not quite working:

```
    print(f"{label['Name']} - {label['Confidence']}")
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have wrong indentation. `response` and the rest of the script is not part of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pics = [f'LP {num}.jpg' for num in range(1, 5)]
for pic in pics :
    request = {
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': 'test1',
            'Name': pic
        }
    }
    response = client.detect_labels(Image=request)
    json_file = json.dumps(response)
    # what is the value of Key? - change it during the loop 
    Path(f"{Key}.json").write_text(json_file)
```

Comment: oh, I think key should be changed to pic or pics, but still does not work.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "does not work". Explain the "Key" as well

Comment: Thanks. For Path(f"{pic}.json").write_text(json_file), instead of saving individual file of the response (4 image files), it only saves single file for the last image only. Does thing anything to do with Python 2 and 3? I am using 3.

Comment: Key - what is the value of this variable during the loop? Your problem is around the Key